# longitude and latitude of a city whithout using Google Map

Tags: latitude-longitude

I'd like, on a mobile app, to display a list of possible cities after a user has entered a few letter and get their GPS position

For example, if the user enters 'Paris', I'd like to have : 
- Paris (France)
- Paris (US, Texas)...

I could use Google Places for that but one needs to either show a google map or a google logo (which is fair enough) and has a limited number of queries each day. Nothing against that, but I wonder if there are alternatives.

I've tried to use Maxmind's cities database. Great database but, alas, only in English. A French or Belgian will type "Bruxelles" but the city name is "Brussels" in Maxmind's DB which limits its use.

Any pointers ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at openmaps? They've got a REST API to access their data: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check wikipedia to find a way locate cities     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aObtaining_geographic_coordinates

There are lots of webservices to get the longitude and latitude information

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at geonames.org where you can donwload the coordinates of "all villages on earth" (40.000)